# Getting a type of of object in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tags, treeview, gettype

in my Winform project, I am using  treeview tag for holding the objects, there are multiple type of objects are stored in treeview.tag and while trying to get the type it is not giving exact type, instead of class name it is giving a long name with some proxy keyword (unlike namespace + class name).

Is there any method to get the actual object type from the tag object

```
var tag= e.Node.Tag;
Type gettype=tag.GetType
//MessageBox.Show(gettype.ToString());          
if (gettype.Equals(typeof(Product)))
{
    var product = (Product)e.Node.Tag;
    //            
}
if (gettype.Equals(typeof(Category)))
{
   var caegory= (Category)e.Node.Tag;
 //            
 }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it is giving"? It would really help if you could provide a [mcve] rather than pseudo-code.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: using entity framework to get the objects, it is assigned to tag property of treeview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "IS" operator for checking whether tag is Product or Category and "AS" operator for the type cast. Below is the example.

```
    var tag = e.Node.Tag;
    if (tag is Product)
    {
        var product = e.Node.Tag as Product;
    }
    if (tag is Category)
    {
        var caegory = e.Node.Tag as Category;
    }
```